# set default data for input in vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I want to set a default value for input of data picker with vue,but the data doesn't show!
in the inspect element show this code:

[image]

script:

```js
   new Vue({
   el:'#app2',
    data: {
         datePicker: '2021/01/05'
    },
    components:{
          datePicker
    }
```

html:

```html
 <div id="app2">
     <date-picker :column="1" v-model="date" mode="single" />
 </div>
```

Comment: you used `v-model="date"` but in data `dataPicker` is present not `date`

Comment: which module are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Add `value-type` it will set the format of binding value and `format` will help to assign the display format.

```
<date-picker :column="1" v-model="datePicker" value-type="YYYY/MM/DD"
    format="YYYY/MM/DD" mode="single" />
```

and

```
new Vue({
            el:'#app2',
            data(){
                return {
                 datePicker: '2021/01/05'
               }
             },
            components:{
                datePicker
            }
```